# String issue in Java with slashes

Tags: java, string

I've a simple code as below and it returns false when I have a space after "N/A" string.

```
String a = "N/A ";
if((a.trim())=="N/A")
{
 System.out.println("true");
}
else{
 System.out.println("false");
}
```

if I remove the space as "N/A" then it returns true. What am I missing here. I know I'm making a silly mistake couldn't figure it out.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use equals() instead of == also fix the (())) issue in if condition

Comment: As well see you have space in `a="N/A "`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using `equals` to compare instead of object identity?

Answer (score 5):

First of all, don't compare strings using `==` operator. Use `if(a.trim().equals("N/A"))`, it should help. Read for example [here](http://www.leepoint.net/notes-java/data/expressions/22compareobjects.html) about comparing objects in Java.

Answer (score 2):

Try below...

```
String a = "N/A ";
if(a.trim().equals("N/A"))
{
 System.out.println("true");
}
else{
 System.out.println("false");
}
```

`==` compares object and `.equals()` compares values.

see [this](http://www.javabeat.net/qna/13-what-is-difference-between-equals-and-/)

Answer (score 1):

Use equals() instead of == also fix the the paratheses issue in if condition